# Dart version mismatch in flutter doctor and pub get

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-doctor, flutter-upgrade

I am trying to install package `lottie: ^1.4.3` and getting following error:

> The current Dart SDK version is 2.17.1 requires SDK version >=2.18.1
> <3.0.0, version solving failed.

I ran flutter doctor -v and it says dart version is 2.18.1

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.2006], locale en-PK)
• Flutter version 3.3.2 on channel stable at E:\Flutter\flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision e3c29ec00c (12 days ago), 2022-09-14 08:46:55 -0500
• Engine revision a4ff2c53d8
• Dart version 2.18.1
• DevTools version 2.15.0
```

`dart --version` output is as follows:

> Dart SDK version: 2.18.1 (stable) (Tue Sep 13 11:42:55 2022 +0200) on
> "windows_x64"

I manually changed following in pubspec.yaml

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.18.1 <3.0.0"
```

I would appreciate if someone could kindly guide me on how to resolve this. I am using Visual Studio Code as the code editor.

Comment: What command did you try for the install?

Comment: Install flutter? https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows

Comment: Exactly manually changing the version of SDK doesnot download the required SDK . Download the latest SDk.

Comment: @SaadBashir I meant for installing your package

Comment: @gretal As you can see in my question I have mentioned that according to flutter doctor -v & dart --version I have the latest version installed.

Comment: @awarrier99 lottie: ^1.4.3 << copy paste in the pubspec.yaml followed by flutter pub get

Comment: Is there any difference if you try `flutter pub add lottie`?

Comment: why would it be? and no there isn't. I tried.

Answer (score 0):

You should also check sub project like `example` folder.

the pub get will check all sub project inside the project, but it will not tell you which one.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't quite get it. Could you kindly elaborate. I should check sub folders for?

Answer (score 0):

Please replace this in pubspec.yaml file.

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.16.2 <3.0.0"
```

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work.